# Python3 - Function that only accepts one argument and returns list using Recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Here is my current function:

```
def fn_one(x):
    _list1 = [3, 1, 5, 3, 8, 5]

    if 5 < x < 14:
        return (fn_one(x-3) * fn_one(x-2)) + fn_one(x-1)

    else:
        if x < 6:
            return _list1[x]

print(fn_one(7))
```

Right now my function only returns an int, what I want to do is return a list that contains the return value from 0 to that int. Example: let's say I call the function by typing  "print(fn_one(4))" then I want to return a list that goes [fn_one(0),fn_one(1),fn_one(2),fn_one(3),fn_one(4)] by **ONLY using recursion.** No for loops or anything like that, and the function must only take **one variable**.

Comment: Why the `if` in the `else` branch?

Comment: Also, why the upper limit of 13? What should happen if you call `fn_one(14)`?

Comment: I don't understand the upper part of the function. How does that relate to your example? Also, what is `fn_one(x-3) * fn_one(x-2)` supposed to do if `fn_one` returns a list?

Comment: Also, if you write that `fn_one(4)` should return `[.., fn_one(4)]`, does that mean that the returned list should be infinitely nested with references to itself? Or did you mean `[_list1[0], ..., _list1[4]]` instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters At this time I do not need to go over 13 so I thought I would take care of it later and as for "what is fn_one(x-3) * fn_one(x-2) supposed to do if fn_one returns a list?" That's the thing I do not currently know how to approach this

Comment: @tobias_k Yeah [_list1[0], ..., _list1[4]] that is what I meant, until things start get messy when they have to go through (fn_one(x-3) * fn_one(x-2)) + fn_one(x-1), I'm still new to python so I do not know how to approach this intuitively

Comment: You don't have to know how to approach this, but you have to at least know what the function is supposed to do. Otherwise we can't help.

Comment: @tobias_k I want the function to take the value of whatever the fn_one(x) I posted might return and put it in a list, then do it for fn_one(x-1). Until it reaches fn_one(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a function `f` such that `f(k)` returns the `k`th term of a sequence, and you want to create a function `g` such that `g(k)` returns `[f(0), ..., f(k)]`.

Basically, in each case first compute `g(k-1)` and then append the latest result to that.

```
def fn_two(x):
    _list1 = [3, 1, 5, 3, 8, 5]

    if 5 < x < 14:
        lst = fn_two(x-1)
        lst.append((lst[x-3] * lst[x-2]) + lst[x-1])
        return lst
    else:
        if x < 6:
            # Return the first x values of _list1
            return _list1[:x+1]
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You already have the first six numbers in _list1, so if `x < 6`, you can just return part or all of that list, as with:

```
if x <= 5:
    return _list1[:x + 2]
```

Otherwise, you want to add onto _list1 and return that:

```
else:
    # returns the list formed by everything below element x
    out_list = fn_one(x - 1)
    # returns using values from the newly generated list
    return out_list + [(out_list[-3] * out_list[-2]) + out_list[-1]]
```

To put it together:

```
def fn_one(x):
    _list1 = [3, 1, 5, 3, 8, 5]

    if x <= 5:
        return _list1[:x + 2]
    else:
        # returns the list formed by everything below element x
        out_list = fn_one(x - 1)
        # returns using values from the newly generated list
        return out_list + [(out_list[-3] * out_list[-2]) + out_list[-1]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort this help me understand :)